# Using IntersectsWith() Method to a drawn triangle

Tags: c#

I am making a snake game using C#. I draw four shapes(Circle, Square, Rectangle, Triangle) same time. If I pass the target as Square, snake has to reach to the Square. If user move the snake to the target and hit,then Win otherwise Fail.

For rectangle, circle, square IntersectsWith() works fine. But for triangle it is not working.Is there any help me?
Here is my code

```
if (snakes.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodSquare))
{
   Win();
}
 if ((snakes.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodCircle))||    (snakes.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodRec)))
{
    restart();
}
```

Works fine
But this won't work

```
if (snakes.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodTrianglePoints))
 {
       //cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Point[]' to 'System.Drawing.Rectangle'                                       
 }
```

Comment: Obviously since .NET `IntersectsWith` method works with rectangle, you need to write your own code to test if custom shapes intersect. By the way, in a 2016 game, it does not make much sense to assume that a snake or a circle is rectangular... By the way, finding intersection is not very complicated mathematic assuming you have gone to school long enough... Using Google, you might be able to find some code like: [Intersection area of a circle and a rectangle (C#)](http://eex-dev.net/index.php?id=100)

Answer (score 1):

`IntersectsWith` certainly will **only** work between `Rectangles`, not triangles nor circles nor ellispis, unless the happen to overlap at the bounds..

However there is a trick to find intersections of pretty much arbitrarily complex shapes, as long as they can be assigned to  a `Region`. One simple way to create a `Region` is using a `GraphicsPath`..

You can add all sorts of shapes to a `GraphicsPath`, pretty much like you would  draw them..

When you have got  `Regions` for both of your shapes you can `Intersect` them and then test if the `Region` is `Empty`.

Here is an example using your shapes; it needs to know on which control or form the shapes are being drawn; let's call it `Control surface`..:

```
using (Graphics g = surface.CreateGraphics())
{
    GraphicsPath gp1 = new GraphicsPath();
    GraphicsPath gp2 = new GraphicsPath();
    GraphicsPath gp3 = new GraphicsPath();
    GraphicsPath gp4 = new GraphicsPath();

    gp1.AddRectangle(fsnakes.SnakeRec[i]);
    gp2.AddPolygon(food.foodTrianglePoints);
    gp3.AddEllipse(food.foodCircle);
    gp4.AddRectangle(food.foodRec);

    Region reg1 = new Region(gp1);
    Region reg2 = new Region(gp2);
    Region reg3 = new Region(gp3);
    reg2.Intersect(reg1);
    reg3.Intersect(reg1);
    reg4.Intersect(reg1);

    if (!reg2.IsEmpty(g)) Win();
    if (!reg3.IsEmpty(g) || !reg4.IsEmpty(g)) restart();
}
```

Comment: Thnkz #TaW. I found a another way. I break the rectangle and triangle pointsinto into point array and use Contain() Method then it worked fine.