# easiest way to check if shapes are overlapping vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, shapes, overlapping

I would like to know, if there is any simple way to check if two shapes (can be any kind of shape) are overlapping? I can work out with circles or rectangles. But I want to check the overlapping of any shapes. For example I draw an L-shape and a triangle on the same form. I want to move the triangle to the L-shape as close as possible from code. Like on the attached pic. I try to do this in vb or in c#

[image]

Comment: How do you build those shapes?

Comment: These shapes would be drawn by user on a windows form. For example user click on 3 points on the form and I create a shape from those points and draw it. After i want to get every shapes and move them next to each other (squeeze them) as much as possible. It's a bit like a 2d packing.

Comment: General solution: Look into Regions. You can build them from graphicsPath from points and test if overlap is empty. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181090/using-intersectswith-method-to-a-drawn-triangle/39182533#39182533) -  Your case: know the shape and look at the corner points.

Comment: seems it pretty much solves my problem. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution for this is to draw the shapes as graphicsPaths and then using the intersect function to see if the intercept:

```
Dim Gp1 as new GraphicsPath
Dim Gp2 as new GraphicsPath

Gp1.Addline(pt1,pt2)
Gp2.Addline(pt2,pt3)
Gp2.Addline(pt3,pt5)


Dim Reg1 as new region(Gp1)
Dim Reg2 as new region(Gp2)

Reg1.Intersect(Reg2)

If Not Reg1.IsEmpty(g) Then

Msgbox "Intersection"

End If
```

link: [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca4a1523-d0b6-465c-b019-de988706997b/intersection-of-2-graphicspaths?forum=Vsexpressvb)

Comment: Don't forget to import: System.Drawing.Drawing2D